# Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error when executing "sudo chroot /mnt"

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, 17.04, chroot

After screwing it up a little resizing Ubuntu's partition on my pc (the process stopped suddenly and I had to recover boot from initramfs) I am trying to repair grub since now it is installed empty (just as a command line utility).

Now I'm following the instructions from the first answer of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). Trying to repair my boot with a LiveUSB, when I execute `sudo chroot /mnt`

I get this error: `bash: /usr/bin/groups: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Then, when I try to execute `update-grub` I get a similar error.

Does anyone know how to solve it? I'm sure I'm using the same OS version on the live session that I have installed (64 bits Ubuntu MATE 17.04). I also have Windows 10.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu!

Comment: I did that. Unfortunately I had no other option. Thanks